# List Definition, disable modal dialog for View item form

Tags: content-type, custom-list

I created two List Definitions with custom add\edit\view forms. Now I want to disable modal 
window only for "view form".
I found solution where `NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE"` was used. 
But this property disable all modal dialogs for specific list. Please help to figure out this issue.

Update:
I want to have modal dialogs for edit and add forms. But when user clicks on the "View item" the page has to be opened without modal dialog.

Thanks.